# vim makefile syntax highlighting issue

Tags: vim, make

Vim doesn't want to highlight my target named " * .o " and its dependencies because of the char ' * '   that I use to target all object files. When I replace the ' * ' by letters the highlighting works correctly.

[image: Vim makefile bad syntax highlighting]

Is this behavior normal or is it a vim bug ? Would be nice to know if there is a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

That rule could be better written as

```
%.o: %.cpp
    clang++ -Wall (...) $<
```

This way, only the source files newer than their object files are compiled. And the highlighting will also work as expected.